# Angular Date Time Picker - set minutes from 59 to 0

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I use this dateTime picker

[dateTime picker](https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker)

If the minutes are set to 59 and I will set it to 0 than currently I have to klick 59 times to set it to 0 (the increment arrow is disabled). Is there another possibility/configuration?

Comment: i think this is good idea to open issue in this repo (and may be to create PR with fix)

Comment: Off: maybe you can try https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker